# Order WP_Query results in order other than ASC or DESC

Tags: wp-query, order

I have pages with a custom field "language" which can be, say, "EN", DE" or "FR".

On a category page I want to output them in a specific order, say, first EN pages, then FR pages, then DE pages.

It seems to only be possible to order "language" by ASC or DESC. Is there a way to sort in a custom order provided in an array?

Comment: What other order could there possibly be? You can't sort in an other way than DESC or ASC... Thats just generally not possible!

Comment: You can order ASC A-B-C or DESC C-B-A, or custom, e.g. "consonants first" B-C-A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use a taxonomy.

If EN, DE and FR are terms then you then loop through them and get the pages on a per term basis.

You can do this in conjunction with a plugin that enables you to manually re-order terms such as this one.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/i-order-terms/

You can then do something like this with your code:

```
// Get all of the terms in the taxonomy
$countries = get_terms( 'countries' );

// Check to ensure there are results returned
if ( !empty( $countries ) && !is_wp_error( $countries ) ) {

    // Loop through the countries
    foreach($countries as $country) {

        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'countries' => $country->slug,
        )

        // Get all of the pages that have this term
        $country_pages = new WP_Query($args);

        // If there are results then print out the country's title and then a list of pages for that country.
        if($country_pages->have_posts()) : ?>

            <h2><?php echo $country->name; ?></h2>

            <ul>

                <?php 
                while($country_pages->have_posts()) : $country_pages->the_post(); ?>

                    <li><?php the_title() ?></li>

                <?php endwhile; 
                // Ensure that the main query is reset
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </ul>

        <?php 
        endif; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that I might have to make separate WP_Querys for each language. I have hardcoded the priority in an array instead of using terms, but it's good to know that I can make the setting available in the admin area defining this as a term.